# How to prevent Angular 2 from appending # to my url?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I've developed a basic to-do app in Angular 2 with basic routing. When I click on a link, Angular automatically appends # at the end of my link. For example, if I want to route to the notes page, Angular open http://localhost:4200/#/notes. Is there any way to disable # from appearing in my urls?

Comment: That's expected if you use the HashLocationStrategy: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles. It's not the default, so you chose this strategy on purpose.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks a ton. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`PathLocationStrategy`** by setting **`false value`** of **`useHash`**

```
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [
    ....
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false })
  ]
})
```

**NOTE**: *This way it works but when you refresh the page, it won't be able to load the current page again. To load it again on refresh, you have to make sure that proper routes are configured at the **server end**. **Client-end(Angular2)** now is not responsible to fetch the current page on refresh that should be done by your **server routing configuration**.*